# "Private" emails invisible to users of a shared exchange mailbox

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013, outlook-2016

Our organization sets up "shared" mailboxes by just creating a regular mailbox and then giving people Full Access in the ecp/exchange admin. It then automaps to their Outlook client. But we are running into the bug where emails sent to that address marked as private, will be invisible. Users can see the count ("Inbox 6"), but not the actual email in Outlook client (only in OWA). The only "fixes" I can find involve a system using Delegate settings. We do not do delegates. No one in our company is a listed delegate nor are these "shared" mailboxes even attached to a client as a standalone where Delegate settings could be managed. Any other resolutions for this?

Comment: Why are people sending private emails to a shared mailbox?

Comment: Who knows? This is external senders. They don't know or care that the address they are sending to is actually a box shared by several people. They just mark crap as "private" or "confidential".

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, the "shared mailbox" is normal mailbox, so you could configure it in the Outlook client and add the users who need to see private emails as delegates with Delegate can see my private items selected. I have tested in my lab, here's a screenshot for your reference(user01 has usr02's full access permission):

Steps:

1. Open user02's mailbox in outlook client.
2. Open account setting, click delegate access, add user01 as a delegate, edit permission and choose "Delegate can see my private items"
   [image]

Then the user01 can see the private mails in user02's mailbox.
[image]

Comment: Every bit of this answer was already addressed in my original post as an unacceptable solution.

Comment: I have done lots of research and i run command add -mailboxfolderpermission to assign permission for users and they still cannot see private items in shared mailbox. It seems to be no way to meet your request.

Comment: That's an acceptable answer, albeit disappointing